# How do I set focus on a div with contenteditable?

Tags: jquery, html

I have  looked through the site and couldn't find a question that solved my problem, so I am asking it here.

I am doing some programming in html and jquery and have bumped into a problem.

**What I want to happen:** I have a div that is user-editable with the contenteditable tag.  When you click the date, the text goes away so you can type in text.

**What happens:** I have a div that is user-editable with the contenteditable tag.  When you click the date, the text goes away, but you can't type in text without clicking the div again..

Here is my code:  http://jsfiddle.net/3Ve4U/.

How do I fix this?  I am using Chrome if that helps anyone.  I don't care about any other browsers, as this is for a private project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it out, and it worked as you said, then I tried to fix it, and came up with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Ve4U/1/

But when I go back to the original, it now works. Odd. Try refreshing, then doing it? Anyways, `.focus()` will focus the element just fine.

Comment: Try changing date to something else in your demo.  Then update.  It doesn't work the first time!  And it worked for me the other times, also.

Comment: @blake305: I actually don't notice that at all on mine. Just on yours, and only the first time.

Comment: You can type in it on the first time? Wow, what version of Chrome (if you are using it) are you running?

Comment: @blake305: Canary 16.0.903.0, I guess that's not quite the same :) If it's a private project, you can install that right? It also works in 15.0.874.83, and that's all the Chrome I have - sorry!